# Very busy garbage collection (95%) with a lots of free memory

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

Our app is now not performing well. When we look at perfmonance, we found that the Garbage collection time is 95% of the execution time. But at the same time, our over all memory usage is quite low - we have lots of free memory as indicated by the TaskManager. Why is that? I thought Garbage collector only got busy when memory pressure is high.

Comment: Is this Android related? If yes, please add Android tag.

Comment: which language or platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From wiki: [Garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29)

> The `Garbage Collection (GC)` is a form of automatic memory management. The garbage collector, or just collector, attempts to reclaim garbage, or memory occupied by objects that are no longer in use by the program.

If you are allocating memory and failing to deallocate it, the *garbage collector* comes into picture. Review your code and see to it that the memory you allocate are deallocated as and when they go out of scope.

Comment: That's what I am thinking too. It's just not easy to confirm it and locate the spot. Is there a way to enlarge the heap size so I can see that the GC comes around less frequently? - I know this is not a solution, just want to confirm this is the issue.

Comment: You can take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java

Comment: Sorry but I think that link is about Java. Mine is a .net app.

Comment: Which is your flavour?(I mean language)

Comment: @TheJoker In a system like, java, Pythono garbage collector regularly deallocates memory. We can call garbage (explicitly) to perform memory clean up operation( as I know we can do in Java). So your line *`If we are failing to deallocate it`* is crucial point.

Comment: Add definition from [Garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science))

Comment: Yeah, it's one aspect of Garbage collection that is independent of the language or platform

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Got it!

Comment: I am sorry but you guys have lost me. I think what I am looking for now is a way to enlarge the heap size of a .Net application. Anybody knows how to do that?

Comment: @user2434400 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301393/can-i-and-do-i-ever-want-to-set-the-maximum-heap-size-in-net?lq=1

Comment: You should really never explicitly deallocate memory in a garbage collected environment.  And even if you do so , the garbage collection rules explicitly prevent you from triggering deallocation or collection.  You can only suggest, based on your knowledge of you application's memory dynamics, when would be a good time to collect.

Answer (score 0):

Task manager memory readings can be totally unrelated to the actual memory allocated to a particular virtual machine.

Comment: Sorry, this is a .net app.

Comment: The clr is a virtual machine too

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are allocating a lot and a lot of objects can be freed. Use [Allocation Tracker](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/track-memory-allocations.html)  to track memory allocations and try to allocate as less as possible. You can even allocate everything on the start of the app and later don't allocate anything. This way you don't "seduce" GC to be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Dont view task manager.try using any .net related memroy viewer,by that you find find out when and where does garabage collector gets into action.I think it might be because you could have a memory leak,try using some tools to get a better idea,about if there is a leak in you app.